# Необходимо при клике на checkbox отображать галочку используя ::after. Как это сделать для данной разметки?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
    
    background: #1B2473;
    color: #787878;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 16px;
   
    }
    .wrapper {
    min-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 20px;
    }


    .form {
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 26px 46px 26px 45px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    }
    .form__title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    }
    .form__group {
    
    }
    .form__input_mg-bottom-13 {
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    }
    .form__input_mg-bottom-16 {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    }
    .form__label-input {
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 100%;
    
     }
    .form__input {
    max-width: 509px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 49px;
    border: 2px solid #787878;
    color: #787878;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 28px;
    }
    .form__input::placeholder {
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 129%;
    color: #cccccc;
    }

    .form__label-checkbox {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 114%;
    margin-bottom: 52px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    }
    /* .form__checkbox {
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 2px solid #787878;
    border-radius: 7px; 
    
    } */
    .form__checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    }
    .form__label-checkbox::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #787878;
    border-radius: 7px; 
    position: relative;
    }
    .form__label-checkbox::after {
    content: 'V';
    
    }
     .form__label-checkbox::before:checked + .form__label-checkbox::after {
     position: absolute;
    }

    .form__btn {
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 67%;
    background: #1A226B;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px 56px 18px 55px;
    }
    .form__btn:hover {
    background: #3e4588;
    }
    .form__button-block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }



      /* ------------- 320 - 768------------------------- */

      @media (max-width: 768px) {

      .form {
        max-width: 728px;
        height: 100%;
        
     }
     .form__title {
        font-size: 60px;
        line-height: 83%;
        margin-bottom: 13px;
      }
     .form__group {
      }
     .form__label-input {
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 67%;
     }
     .form__input {
        max-width: 638px;
        margin-top: 8px;        
     }
     .form__input::placeholder {
        color: #cccccc;
     }
    
    .form__label-checkbox {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 89%;
        margin-bottom: 64px;
    }
    .form__checkbox {
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
    }
    .form__button-block {
    }
    .form__btn {
        max-width: 220px;
        min-height: 80px;
        padding: 32px 64px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
       }
      }
```

```html
    
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,700&display=swap" 
       rel="stylesheet" />
       <title>Form</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <form action="#" class="form">

            <h1 class="form__title">Вход</h1>

            <div class="form__group">
                <label for="" class="form__label-input">Email</label>
                <input class="form__input form__input_mg-bottom-13" name="email" type="email" 
         value="trubnikoviv84@gmail.com" disabled>
            </div>

            <div class="form__group">
                <label for="" class="form__label-input">Пароль</label>
                <input class="form__input form__input_mg-bottom-16" name="pass" type="password" 
        placeholder="Введите пароль" required> 
            </div>

            <div class="form__group">
                <label class="form__label-checkbox">
                    <input class="form__checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"> 
                    Я согласен получать обновления на почту
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form__button-block">
                <button class="form__btn" type="submit">Войти</button> 
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь хитрость заключается в том, что оригинальный `<input>` скрывается и за отрисовку будет отвечать следующий элемент:

```
/* Оригинальный input */
.form__checkbox{
  display: none;
}
/* Обычное состояние */
.form__checkbox + span::after {
  content: "☐";
  font-size: 2em;
  position: relative;
}
/* Состояние с галочкой */
.form__checkbox:checked + span::after {
  content: "☑︎";
}
```

В качестве галочки использовал символы UTF-8.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
    
    background: #1B2473;
    color: #787878;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 16px;
   
    }
    .wrapper {
    min-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 20px;
    }


    .form {
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 26px 46px 26px 45px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    }
    .form__title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    }
    .form__group {
    
    }
    .form__input_mg-bottom-13 {
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    }
    .form__input_mg-bottom-16 {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    }
    .form__label-input {
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 100%;
    
     }
    .form__input {
    max-width: 509px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 49px;
    border: 2px solid #787878;
    color: #787878;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 28px;
    }
    .form__input::placeholder {
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 129%;
    color: #cccccc;
    }

    .form__label-checkbox {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 114%;
    margin-bottom: 52px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    }
    /* .form__checkbox {
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 2px solid #787878;
    border-radius: 7px; 
    
    } */
    .form__checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    }
   /* .form__label-checkbox::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #787878;
    border-radius: 7px; 
    position: relative;
    }*/
    
    .form__checkbox{
      display: none;
    }
   .form__checkbox + span::after {
      content: "☐";
      font-size: 2em;
      position: relative;
    }
   .form__checkbox:checked + span::after {
      content: "☑︎";
    }

    .form__btn {
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 67%;
    background: #1A226B;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px 56px 18px 55px;
    }
    .form__btn:hover {
    background: #3e4588;
    }
    .form__button-block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }



      /* ------------- 320 - 768------------------------- */

      @media (max-width: 768px) {

      .form {
        max-width: 728px;
        height: 100%;
        
     }
     .form__title {
        font-size: 60px;
        line-height: 83%;
        margin-bottom: 13px;
      }
     .form__group {
      }
     .form__label-input {
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 67%;
     }
     .form__input {
        max-width: 638px;
        margin-top: 8px;        
     }
     .form__input::placeholder {
        color: #cccccc;
     }
    
    .form__label-checkbox {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 89%;
        margin-bottom: 64px;
    }
    .form__checkbox {
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
    }
    .form__button-block {
    }
    .form__btn {
        max-width: 220px;
        min-height: 80px;
        padding: 32px 64px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
       }
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,700&display=swap" 
       rel="stylesheet" />
       <title>Form</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <form action="#" class="form">

            <h1 class="form__title">Вход</h1>

            <div class="form__group">
                <label for="" class="form__label-input">Email</label>
                <input class="form__input form__input_mg-bottom-13" name="email" type="email" 
         value="trubnikoviv84@gmail.com" disabled>
            </div>

            <div class="form__group">
                <label for="" class="form__label-input">Пароль</label>
                <input class="form__input form__input_mg-bottom-16" name="pass" type="password" 
        placeholder="Введите пароль" required> 
            </div>

            <div class="form__group">
                <label class="form__label-checkbox">
                    <input class="form__checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"> 
                    <span> </span> Я согласен получать обновления на почту
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form__button-block">
                <button class="form__btn" type="submit">Войти</button> 
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: А как с помощью after сделать зачеканый чекбокс?

Comment: Ну можно поменять местами символы `☐` и `☑︎`, тогда по умолчанию он будет выделенный. А по другому только если в тег `<input>` вписать `checked`.

Comment: @ИгорьТрубников я просто не до конца понимаю что именно вы имеете в виду? что вы хотите получить? и как вы хотите это сделать? Посмотрите сниппет в ответе, нажмите кнопку **выполнить код**. Потом раскройте на всю страницу, если форма не влезает.

Comment: @ИгорьТрубников чуть подкорректировал ответ. Надеюсь, так понятнее...

Answer (score 0):

```
 .form__checkbox {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.form__checkbox:checked::after{
    visibility: visible;
}

.form__checkbox::after{
    content: "\2714";
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
    
    background: #1B2473;
    color: #787878;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 16px;
   
    }
    .wrapper {
    min-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 20px;
    }


    .form {
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 26px 46px 26px 45px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    }
    .form__title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    }
    .form__group {
    
    }
    .form__input_mg-bottom-13 {
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    }
    .form__input_mg-bottom-16 {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    }
    .form__label-input {
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 100%;
    
     }
    .form__input {
    max-width: 509px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 49px;
    border: 2px solid #787878;
    color: #787878;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 28px;
    }
    .form__input::placeholder {
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 129%;
    color: #cccccc;
    }

    .form__label-checkbox {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 114%;
    margin-bottom: 52px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    }
    /* .form__checkbox {
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 2px solid #787878;
    border-radius: 7px; 
    
    } */
 .form__checkbox {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.form__checkbox:checked::after{
    visibility: visible;
}

.form__checkbox::after{
    content: "\2714";
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    cursor: pointer;

}

    .form__btn {
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 67%;
    background: #1A226B;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px 56px 18px 55px;
    }
    .form__btn:hover {
    background: #3e4588;
    }
    .form__button-block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }



      /* ------------- 320 - 768------------------------- */

      @media (max-width: 768px) {

      .form {
        max-width: 728px;
        height: 100%;
        
     }
     .form__title {
        font-size: 60px;
        line-height: 83%;
        margin-bottom: 13px;
      }
     .form__group {
      }
     .form__label-input {
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 67%;
     }
     .form__input {
        max-width: 638px;
        margin-top: 8px;        
     }
     .form__input::placeholder {
        color: #cccccc;
     }
    
    .form__label-checkbox {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 89%;
        margin-bottom: 64px;
    }

    
    .form__checkbox {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.form__checkbox:checked::after{
    visibility: visible;
}

.form__checkbox::after{
    content: "\2714";
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
 
}
    
    
    .form__button-block {
    }
    .form__btn {
        max-width: 220px;
        min-height: 80px;
        padding: 32px 64px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
       }
      }
```

```html
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,700&display=swap" 
       rel="stylesheet" />
       <title>Form</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <form action="#" class="form">

            <h1 class="form__title">Вход</h1>

            <div class="form__group">
                <label for="" class="form__label-input">Email</label>
                <input class="form__input form__input_mg-bottom-13" name="email" type="email" 
         value="trubnikoviv84@gmail.com" disabled>
            </div>

            <div class="form__group">
                <label for="" class="form__label-input">Пароль</label>
                <input class="form__input form__input_mg-bottom-16" name="pass" type="password" 
        placeholder="Введите пароль" required> 
            </div>

            <div class="form__group">
                <label class="form__label-checkbox">
                    <input class="form__checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"> 
                    Я согласен получать обновления на почту
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form__button-block">
                <button class="form__btn" type="submit">Войти</button> 
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </body>
       </html>
```